# Writing a SQL query about customers having all orders with just one store

Tags: sql

I have the following relational scheme :

- Store (store Id, store_name)
- Toy(toy ID, name)
- Customer(Customer ID, name)
- Order(order ID, Customer ID)
- Olines (order ID, Store ID, toy ID)

I want to write a query in SQL to find customer Id of all customers who have all their orders with just one store and that store cannot be 'Toys R Us'.

I am new to SQL and not sure how to go about this. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Kindly share sample data, query you tried and desired output

Comment: You have to join tables, group them and restrict by having clause

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. just replace the table name and column name as per you have.

```
select a.customerid 
from (
    select or.customerid,st.storeid,count(*) count 
    from Order or, Onlines on, Store st 
    where or.orderid=on.orderid and on.storeid=st.storeid and st.store_name!='Toy R Us' 
    group by or.customerid,st.storeid) a 
where a.count=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists clause for this

```
; With cte as(
Select distinct name , c.[Customer ID],s.[store Id] 
From customer c  join order o
On c.[Customer ID]=o.[Customer ID]
Join olines l
On o.[order ID]=l.[order ID]
Join store s
On s.[store Id]=l.[store Id] and not s.[store_name]='Toys R Us')

Select * 
from cte c1 
where
 not exists(
 Select 1 
 from cte c2 
 where c2.[Customer ID]=c1.[Customer ID] and c2.[store Id]=<>c1.[store Id] 
 )
```